# StoreJet 25M3 USB 3.0 1TB beeping?

Tags: usb, power

So my storejet started beeping just now, the beeps only occur when I supply power via the a USB port, and the beeping only lasts for about 5 seconds and after that the beeping is gone and it just sits there not doing anything. The storejet isn't working at all, no blue light is coming of the LED, also, all this happened when I unplugged the storejet (Stupid me), when netbeans stopped responding and all the files that I was working with on that project was stored only, and only on the storejet :(

Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong? Except the fact that I unplugged it in such a stupid way...

Comment: Does the drive show up in Disk Management (Start > Run > diskmgmt.msc)? Try and locate a manual online to see what the beeps mean. If the disk is inaccessible even from Linux then you might need to open it up and attach the drive directly (this will void the warranty), but this may not be possible depending on the controller.

Comment: Are you plugging it into a USB 3 port? Did you try a different USB 3 cable?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check and tell us whether it shows up in Windows Disk Management. Post a screenshot.
2. If the external does not have a drive letter, give it a drive letter.
3. Plug it into other ports and check.
4. Change the cable and see whether it makes a difference.
5. Plug it into another PC and check what happens.